# Kibana: Error Could not reach http://:9200/_nodes. If you are using a proxy, ensure it is configured correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Kibana is unable to load the data from elastic search which works on port 9201. But i get the message as Error Could not reach http://:9200/_nodes. If you are using a proxy, ensure it is configured correctly.

I have set the port as 9201 in Kibana config file. But still it tries to get the data from 9200.

Can anyone pls help me out?

Comment: Paste here your `config.js` file.

Comment: I have pasted only the middle portion of config.js where i have made the port changes (whole file is too long to be pasted here)  * Note: this can also be an object if you want to pass options to the http client. For example:
     *
     elasticsearch: {server: "http://localhost:9201", withCredentials: true}+
     *
     */
    elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9201",

    /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
     *
     * ==== default_route
     *
     * This is the default landing page when you don't specify a dashboard to load. You can specify

Comment: Try using something like `elasticsearch: "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":9201"`. Edit the question the next time to add the configuration files instead of using the comments section for this, please.

Comment: Its giving the same error even after making mentioned changes.

Comment: Can you try in an incognito window? Maybe your browser is caching the `config.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to kill ElasticSearch proccess by:

```
kill -9 {id}
```

and run it once again.